# Beginning nethack, how to use bags

Tags: nethack

After scrutinising various lists of commands and browsing a few wikis, I am missing something obvious:

What commands do I use to put things into a bag, list the contents of a bag and take things out of a bag?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Containers (bags, boxes, chests, etc.) in your inventory are treated differently from those on the ground (which you can access using [#loot](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Loot) command).  For bags in your inventory, treat them like tools and use them with [[a]pply](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Apply).  This will then bring up the menu to add, remove, or just view the items within.